# Wrong links to posts in GitHub pages with Jekyll

Tags: git, github, jekyll, github-pages

I have started using GutHub-Pages. I am using [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) and my `gh-pages` repository has the following structure:

```
gh-pages (repo)
+-site
| +-_posts
|   +-2016-02-15-post1.md
| +-_config.yml
| +-index.html
+-notes.md
```

My `index.html` is like this:

```
---
layout: default
---

<div class="home">
  <h1 class="page-heading">Posts</h1>
  <ul class="post-list">
    {% for post in site.posts %}
      <li>
        <span class="post-meta">{{ post.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}</span>
        <h2><a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  <p class="rss-subscribe">subscribe <a href="{{ "/feed.xml" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">via RSS</a></p>
</div>
```

#### Wrong paths

So I can get to my pages url: `http://<username>.github.io/<project-name>` and land in `index.html` just fine. But when i click on a link post, I get this address:

```
http://<username>.github.io/jekyll/update/2016/02/15/post1.html
```

Which leads to a 404 as the correct path is:

```
http://<username>.github.io/jekyll/<project-name>/update/2016/02/15/post1.html
```

The project name folder is not counted!

Answer (score 2):

In `_config.yml`, set

```
baseurl: /project-name
```